# In k8s, how to automatically add a root certificate of a self-signed certificate between pods?

Tags: kubernetes, ssl

I created a self-signed certificate, my HTTP service pod mounts this self-signed certificate, I hope other pods can trust the certificate when accessing this http service, now I can only mount the root certificate in the client's pod Then use update-ca-certificates inside the pod to add certificate trust.
Is there a way in k8s to automatically add this root certificate to all newly created pods without requiring me to manually mount the root certificate and then add trust. Because I don't know how the pods are created later, and I can't ask for the creation of pods in the future The person who mounted my root certificate

Answer (score 1):

Better to use helm, as that is designed for templating, if you want to have workaround, then it should work

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  annotations:
    version: 0.0.1
  name: job_name # this also need to be overridden otherwise it will throw an error as cmd is immutable
  labels:
    app: batch
    io.service: batch
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: batch-1
        image: alpine
        command: ["/bin/sh"]
        args: ["-c", "echo the value of argument1= ARG_1  and argument2= ARG_2"]
      restartPolicy: Never
```

and here we will override `args` and job `name`

```
sed -e "s/ARG_1/my-arg1/g" -e "s/ARG_2/my-arg2/g" -e "s/job_name/myawsomejob-name/"  demo.yaml  | kubectl apply -f -
```

[image]